# installing windows alongside ubuntu. how to partition?

Tags: partitioning

I have a 250 gb hdd and a 1 tb ssd. I currently have ubuntu 18.04 installed. I want to install windows 10 alongside it. I'll be using windows to play games on steam, photoshop and for some hardware which can only use windows. I'll primarily be using ubuntu.

```
sda             238.5G                                                     
├─sda1 ext4       731M                                                     
├─sda2              1K                                                     
└─sda5 ext4      18.6G /                                                   
sdb             931.5G                                                     
├─sdb1 vfat       512M                                                     
├─sdb2 ext4       732M /media/artemis/b2896d21-6ba9-46fc-99aa-ed497a5998fd 
└─sdb3 swap      14.9G [SWAP]                                              
sr0              1024M
```

Any suggestions for how to partition windows 10?

Comment: Is sdb1 an ESP - efi system partition used for UEFI boot? And are both drives gpt partitioned? Windows only installs to gpt with UEFI and only to MBR for BIOS boot. Best to have both systems in same boot mode. And if newer UEFI hardware better to have both systems using UEFI to boot from gpt partitioned drives.

Comment: Looks like this is a messed up Ubuntu scenario before you've even started on a dual boot. You have Ubuntu installed on both disks. You should first decide which disk for Ubuntu and which one for Windows....or have them both sharing the one disk, with the second disk just for data. Also Windows should always be the first system installed with a dual boot.

Comment: how can you tell it's installed on both? any examples of what it should look like? is the ext 4 with 732 m on both?

Comment: You have your swap and boot partitions on your 1 TB disk with your root partition on the 250 GB. Since both sda1 and sdb2 are virtually the same small size, I'm guessing sda1 is the original and sdb2/media is sda1 mounted on sdb2.

By the way, don't you mean your 250 GB disk is your SSD and the 1 TB is the HDD, just to be clear?

Comment: @PaulBenson, yes. I bought this a while ago and forgot. Can you show my a link to a proper dual install of windows and Ubuntu and of the partitioning?

Comment: I'd recommend [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/), but in your case I'd start from scratch (no operating systems then install W10 first on SSD and follow instructions to install Ubuntu afterwards). What media are you using to install Windows from? Do you have a DR license for W10 or a product key? Have you backed up any data first?

Comment: I just downloaded the free windows 10 iso from microsoft. It was a fresh install yesterday and it's a usb. I'm just going to install both os on the hdd and then put steam on the ssd for both versions (100 for windows and 50 for ubuntu) and swap.

Comment: W10 - free ISO?? Are you sure about that? W10 needs to be activated and you need a MS license to do that successfully. Maybe you already have one. Have you tested the W10 USB that your computer will boot from it OK before you do anything else? You should install W10 and Ubuntu on the **SSD**. Use the HDD for data storage.

Comment: Well I may still have a key but if not I'll just buy it. I installed windows (in uefi mode) and it's working fine. I partitioned everything on the hard drive with 200gb for the primary drive and I created a 100 GB drive on the SSD for Steam. I was going to do the same for Ubuntu except on 50 GB on the SSD for Steam. But now I am encountering a problem where Windows refuses to stop booting so I haven't been able to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way. On the main drive (my SSD) I already had Ubuntu installed.

Ubuntu was on /dev/sda5 inside /dev/sda1 extended partition.
When I installed Windows 7, I either had space already unpartitioned on my SSD or I shrunk the extended partition and made unpartitioned space from the remainder.

There is one thing you should keep in mind, let the space you are going to use for the windows install be unpartitioned not already NTFS or anything else.

Boot from the USB/DVD windows installer, install to the unpartitioned space.
Windows will create (in my case) /dev/sda2 as its boot partition and /dev/sda3 as its file system partition.

After you are done installing windows, boot up from an Ubuntu live DVD/USB and in the terminal make sure to install grub (boot manager) again to /dev/sda1.

If you do it like this normally you should get a working dual-boot (at least for what I am running Ubuntu 18.04/Windows 7)